# OpenGL ES: Well defined way to discard primitive in vertex shader

Tags: opengl-es, shader, nan, undefined-behavior, vertex-shader

My vertex shader decides to discard some triangles. If a triangle should be discarded, what I currently do is set the output position to NaN:

```
gl_Position = vec4(intBitsToFloat(int(0xFFC00000u)), intBitsToFloat(int(0xFFC00000u)), intBitsToFloat(int(0xFFC00000u)), intBitsToFloat(int(0xFFC00000u)));
```

`intBitsToFloat(int(0xFFC00000u))` is floating point NaN.

This works on the platforms I tested it on.

However, Section 2.3.4.1 of the [OpenGL ES 3.2 Spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.2/es_spec_3.2.pdf) states that

> The special values Inf and −Inf encode values with magnitudes too
> large to be represented; the special value NaN encodes “Not A Number”
> values resulting from undefined arithmetic operations such as 0/0.
> Implementations are permitted, but not required, to support Inf's and
> NaN's in their floating-point computations.

So my approach might actually yield undefined behavior.
What's the proper, well defined OpenGL ES 3.x way to completely discard a triangle in the vertex shader?

Answer (score 1):

The result is required to be consistent, even if NaN is not generated. If you set all 3 vertices to NaN (or whatever the fallback value turns out to be) then they are going to be coincident locations. Any two coincident vertices in a triangle = zero area = culled. So I think this works in either case ...